# ReactJS AXIOS doesn't update data from Django backend when page refreshes

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I have been trying to update data from my backend, which is based on Python Django. I've noticed that the data is not getting updated when page refreshes. `axios` **fetches the** **data once and then doesnt update** until i restart myserver. I have tried multiple solutions from SO but nothing works. Can anyone help?

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import StatBox from "../components/StatBox";

function Bucketsize() {
  // State variable for storing data
  const [data, setData] = useState({size: '', unit: ''});

  // Function to fetch data
  const fetchDevices = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/bucketsize/", {});
      const size = res.data.size;
      const unit = res.data.unit;
      setData({ size, unit });
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDevices();
  }, []); 
 
  return (
    <StatBox data={data.size} size={data.unit} heading="Bucket Size" />
  );
}

export default Bucketsize;
```

**This is my views.py**

```
class Bucketsize(APIView):
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    from rest_framework import status
    import json

    @staticmethod
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(request):
        from .awsdata.generalstats.bucketsize import bucket_size
        size, unit = bucket_size()
     
        return Response({"size": size, "unit": unit})
```

**This is the code that fetches data from AWS and called in views.py**

```
import boto3
# from .credentials.credential import bucketname

def get_bucket_size(bucket_name):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    size = 0

    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name):
        for obj in page.get('Contents', []):
            size += obj['Size']

    return size

bucket_name = 'bucket_name' 
size = get_bucket_size(bucket_name)

# Determine the appropriate unit based on the size
units = ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']
unit_index = 0
while size >= 1024 and unit_index < len(units) - 1:
    size /= 1024
    unit_index += 1

# Format the size with two decimal places
bucketsize = '{:.2f}'.format(size)
 

def bucket_size():
    unit = units[unit_index]
    return bucketsize, unit

# a,b = bucket_size()
# print(a,b)
```

I have tried to fetch data using an asynchronous function. Doesnt work. My backend has python files that fetches data from `AWS Timestream` everytime its executed.

**Note: The python scripts at the backend take around 5-10seconds to execute to fetch data from AWS**

Comment: Have you tested your api using something like postman? Too make sure its a problem from your React app. Also, are you sure that your api is set up to respond to a post request? Maby you need to use a get method insted. Are you getting any errors in your network tab in the devtools of your browser?

Comment: Yes it is set up to respond to post request. Also, im able to fetch the data using axios but when i refresh the page, the data doesnt get updated unless i restart my backend. Also, there are no errors shown.